# How to find R approximation for CLT

Tags: r, binomial-coefficients

**The distribution for the number of faulty lightbulbs is the binomial distribution. i.e. the number of faulty lightbulbs is:**

[image]

**Use R to produce a graphical representation that compares the true pmf for the number of faulty lightbulbs found and its approximation using the central limit theorem.**

So I've produced a graph for the pmf in r as using the code below. However I'm having an issue with the CLT part of the question. We haven't covered that part of the syllabus yet.

```
n <- 100
p <- 0.015
# pmf
x <- (0:n)
px <- dbinom(x,n,p) 
# Plot pmf
plot(x,px,type="h",ylab="p(x)" ,main=paste("Binomial(",n,",",p,")",sep=""))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if this is what you want for the CLT plot:

```
xclt <- seq(0,n,by = 0.001)
clt <- dnorm(xclt,mean = n*p,sd = sqrt(n*p*(1-p)))
lines(xclt,clt,col="red",lty= 2)
legend(80,0.3,legend = c("bin","clt"),col = c("black","red"),lty = c(1,2))
```

such that
[image]